# QuickBlox add UserCustomData

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

How to add few custom data fields for new QBUser?  I know how to make it for single custom data field.

```
public static String customDataToString(String key,String value) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    setJsonValue(jsonObject, key,value);


    return jsonObject.toString();
}

private static void setJsonValue(JSONObject jsonObject, String key, String value) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
        try {
            jsonObject.put(key, value);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Should I use jsonarray or something to make it work with multiple fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's custom data is just a string and you can put any values right here.

To put many fields you can user JSON for example.